# Selenium Java, NoSuchElementException: no such element

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests

Here is my code:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://ecdluk.psionline.com");
    Thread.sleep(10000);  // Let the user actually see something!
    WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.id("loginEmail"));
    searchBox.sendKeys("Test");
    searchBox.submit();
    Thread.sleep(5000);  // Let the user actually see something!
    driver.quit();
```

I have tested this code by changing the url to another form and it works fine however I cannot get it to see the id of the login form.

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:
>   no such element: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"id","selector":"loginEmail"}   (Session info:
>   chrome=55.0.2883.87)   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174
>   (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Windows NT
>   10.0.14393 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: That's because there is no element with `id="loginEmail"`. On different web-sites input fields for same purpose ussually have different attribute values, so you cannot use same locators for different sites.

Comment: Maybe I'm paranoid, but I'm a bit scared to click on the link based on this question and a similar previous one with a similar type of user. My paranoid brain is telling me there is a scheme to steal my cookies and login to my bank accounts.